# Is it good to hide other functions if a user needs to focus on a task?

Tags: user-behavior, navigation, users, task-completion

We have a desktop app that allows consultant to accept customers. On this app, the consultant can be on 2 statuses: Available or Away.

I am thinking of hiding other menu items if the status is "Available" because on this status, the consultant would need to be on guard of incoming customers. That's the only thing he should focus on (as if in a call center). If he goes to other pages of the desktop app, he may miss an incoming call.

If the consultant wants to do other things, he can set himself as "Away", then all the other functionalities would be enabled again.

I feel that it makes the whole process simpler without the need to worry of other scenarios that may happen.

Answer (score 2):

Something's you should consider is that you would have different customers with different perspectives. Others may want what you are thinking if doing, while some may want to be able to receive their calls on any page. I advice that you put a notification on every page that tells them they have an incoming call because having you customers not able to multitask on your site would be to me a bad idea.

As for the consultant being able to set himself away is not a bad idea. You make it that if the consultant set himself away he knows he won't be receiving calls or some other functionalities you may want to remove.

But if this app is made for a company you may want to ask them what they want. If its a plugin or app you want people to download and use for their companies, you may want to consider my advice.